# Laravel 8 eloquent missing 1 field while creating a sql query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got a problem with eloquent, I have a controller with such a code

```
$pivot = MovieGenre::where('movie_id', $id)->delete();
        if($request->input('genres')){
            foreach ($request->input('genres') as $genre) {
                $pivot = MovieGenre::create([
                    'movie_id' => $id,
                    'genre_id' => $genre,
                ]);
            }
        }
```

and for example 2 more same pivots that's working, that pivots are same and controller made same way
while I'm trying to use it I got an error [image]

This query missing 'genre_id' in the query but I gave this field in method CREATE from pivot model.
Model file is empty. just 'extends Pivot'

Comment: why are you extending `Pivot` when you are using it directly like a regular model?

Comment: @lagbox ohh, thought that's the only way to add a record there, is some other way?

Comment: The custom pivot model is for use when using the Belongs To Many Relationship setup between your Models ... you could just make your `MovieGenre` model extend `Model` and make those fields fillable

Comment: @lagbox I have belongsToMany Relationship that's the way it extending pivot

Comment: you are not using that relationship in that example at all, you are directly interacting with the pivot table; there is no Eloquent relationship here in this example ... you can literally do everything you are doing now with 1 line of code if you used the actual relationship from Movie to Genre

Comment: @lagbox I don't know that there is the way to create records other way but I'm using it in other scopes, when I showing movie I just using 1 word to select all genres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the relationship from a `Movie` model to `Genre` model here. You are directly interacting with a pivot table (which would just be a regular Model at this point, not a custom pivot).

You can simplify all of this if you used the relationship from `Movie` to `Genre`:

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    public function genres()
    {
        // convention would name the table genre_movie
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class, 'movie_genre')->withTimestamps();
    }
}

Movie::findOrFail($id)->genres()->sync((array) $request->input('genres'));
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Many to Many - Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns) `withTimestamps`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Inserting & Updating Related Models - Many to Many - Syncing Associations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) `sync`

If you don't want to use the relationships then make `MovieGenre` a regular Model and set those fields as fillable:

```
class MovieGenre extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'movie_id',
        'genre_id',
    ];
}
```